# Pass attribute from `<a>` to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to get the `value` or `id` from an `<a>` tag and use it inside a JavaScript function.

```js
function myFunction(qiizName, x) {
  val = 1;
  console.log("question number" + qiizName);
  console.log("number question" + x.value);
  console.log("number question" + x.id);
}
```

```php
echo"<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='#home' class='active' >module</a></li>";

$i=0;
while ( $module_row = mysqli_fetch_array($module)) {
    $total=$module_row['total_question'];   
    $id=$module_row['id'];  

    echo '<li><a href="javascript:myFunction(1,this)" 
           id="'.$total.'" 
           value="'.$total.'">\''.$module_row['nom'].'\' </a></li>';

    $i++;
} 

echo "</ul>";
```

For example:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction(1,this)" id="2" value="2">cpp</a>
```

I'd expect to get `value` "2" and `id` "2".

I tried the same code in another project and it works, but in this case it doesn't work at all. It returns "undefined" in the console.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Why not pass values for the id and the value directly into the method?  I wasn't aware an <a> tag could have a valid `value` attribute.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cufj5Lab/  It appears that for a href javascript call the 'this' is passed as the window.  If you change it to an onclick, the 'this' becomes the element.  Value is still undefined though, as I'd expect, since value isn't an attribute for a link.  https://jsfiddle.net/cufj5Lab/1/  Dataset works though.

Comment: True, `value` attributes are not intended for `<a>` tags. I suggest using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **[`<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)** does not have a `value` attribute, that is invalid HTML. Only form fields have a `value`. You can set up a custom **[`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** (shown below) and access it in JavaScript with the **[element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** property.

Also, while it is now valid to give an element an `id` that starts with a number, it is not advisable as this can cause confusion and issues down the line.

Next, don't use the `href` attribute for embedding JavaScript (i.e. `href="javascript:..."`) as that technique to launch some JavaScript when the link gets clicked is literally about 20 years old and very outdated. If you really want to give the user something to click and it won't cause navigation, then don't use an `<a>` at all as it will confuse screen readers, you'll need to cancel the native `click` behavior and it is semantically incorrect. Just about every HTML element supports a `click` event and can be styled to look like a hyperlink.

Also, follow modern standards and best-practices by separating your HTML from your JavaScript. It all starts by getting a JavaScript reference to the element(s) you want to work with and from there, you can extract or modify any aspect of it that you wish **so you really don't need to "pass" any data to your function** as the function will already be "bound" to the element that caused the event function to be invoked and you can get the data you need with the `this` object reference.

```js
// Get a reference to the element you wish to work with:
var element = document.getElementById("two");

// Set up event handler in JavaScript, not in the href attribute of HTML
element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // You have access to all of the element's attributes and child content
  // via the "this" object refence because the element that caused this 
  // function event handler to run gets bound to "this".
  console.log("ID is: " + this.id);
  console.log("data-value is: " + this.dataset.value);  
  console.log("Content is: " + this.textContent);  
}
```

```css
.clickable { cursor:pointer; user-select:none; text-decoration:underline; }
```

```html
<div id="two" data-value="2" class="clickable">cpp</div>
```